# Add and remove an element (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I'm trying to add or remove fields to my form.

When the user click on the `"+"` the parent is duplicated.
When the user click on the `"-"` the parent is removed

The problem is, when the user click on the `"+"`, the parent is duplicated under the `"+"` , but i would like to duplicate it between the `'+'` and the parent

**Here is my code**

```
  $('#ajoute-champ').on('click', function (){
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="input-group">
            <label for="ref_clients0" class="input-group-addon fa-right">
                Référence client<i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="ref_clients0" name="ref_clients[0]"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez la référence client" value="">
            <a class="supprime-champ trash-button-field">
               <i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash"></i>
            </a></div>');
    });
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
      <label for="ref_clients0" class="input-group-addon fa-right">
          Référence client<i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="ref_clients0" name="ref_clients[0]"
        class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez la référence client"
        value="">
      <a class="supprime-champ trash-button-field"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash"></i></a>
</div>
```

Ajouter un nouveau champ Référence client

Comment: Where is the `#ajoute-champ` element? Also, your JS is invalid due to the line breaks within the string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I added the line breaks to remove the ugly scrollbars

Comment: I edited my post, i forgot the #ajoute-champ

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12 rem-pad-left" id="add-row">  
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="ref_clients" class="input-group-addon fa-right">Référence client<i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    <input type="text" id="ref_clients" name="ref_clients[]" class="form-control " placeholder="Entrez la référence client" value="">
    <a class="supprime-champ trash-button-field"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash"></i></a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$("body").on("click", ".add_field_button",function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < 10){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $("body #add-row").append('<div class="input-group"><label for="ref_clients" class="input-group-addon fa-right">Référence client<i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><input type="text" id="ref_clients" name="ref_clients[]" class="form-control " placeholder="Entrez la référence client" value=""><a class="supprime-champ trash-button-field"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash"></i></a></div>');
    }
});});</script>
```

Comment: This is not what i want.
Here, you are just restricting the max number of box

Comment: yes but what i want is :

Add my box between the <a> and the firtst <div class="input-group">